# What are the differences between the military ranks of the Spanish military and those of Latin America and how do they compare to those of the U.S.?

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales, vocabulario-técnico, hispanoamérica

Primero mi pregunta en español:

**¿Cuál son las differencias entre los rangos militares de las fuerzas armadas de España y los de las fuerzas armadas en Latinoamérica, y cómo se comparan a los de los EE.UU.?**

Details in English:

Recently, I was attempting to translate into English some Spanish military ranks.  In the process, I began to realize that there might be some significant differences in meaning.  For example, the role and place in the hierarchy of a first lieutenant in the U.S. military might have a slightly different role and place in the hierarchy of a Latin American military.

More specifically, a first lieutenant in the United States has hierarchy over a second lieutenant, but I'm not sure if that is the case in Latin American militaries.  The Wikipedia article, [**"Cadete oficial"**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadete_oficial) and its description of "teniente primero" and "teniente segundo" is, specifically, what launched this line of inquiry.  I realize this is an article on a naval school in Peru and not Peru's navy, but often the ranking system is similar as it is preparing them for the real army, navy, air force, et cetera.  Regardless of similarities or lack thereof between a military school and the military, it made me wonder about the differences between the armed forces of Latin America, where they exist, and by how much from one country to the next.

My solution to this was to visit a chart of NATO ranks to see the grades listed for the Spanish military and in so doing, would at least have a better understanding of how the pay grades correspond, but this only works when, and if, I can find corresponding information for a Latin American military.  As an example, I've included an image of Peruvian ranks below:

[image]
*The image above comes from a page titled [**"Marina de Guerra del Perú"**](https://www.marina.mil.pe/page/grados)*

As you can see, the names of the various ranks are listed, but not the grades, leaving some uncertainty regarding how well they actually correspond.

Though the NATO chart was easy to find and easy to read, I'm still left wondering how the various military ranks of each Latin American military on the other side of the pond correspond with those of Spain.

If this question is too difficult to answer, I would be happy to do the research myself, but would any of you be so kind as to suggest some useful resources on this topic?

Detalles en español:

Recientemente, estaba intentando traducir al inglés unos rangos militares.  En el proceso, comencé a darme cuenta de que podría haber diferencias significativas de sentido para algunos de ellos.  Por ejemplo, la función y posición en la jerarquía de un teniente primero en las fuerzas armadas de los Estados Unidos podría ser algo ligeramente diferente en otra fuerza armada.

Más específicamente, un teniente primero en los Estados Unidos tiene jerarquía sobre un teniente segundo, pero no estoy segura si eso es el caso en fuerzas armadas latinoamericanas.  El artículo de la Wikipedia, [**"Cadete oficial"**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadete_oficial) y su descripción de "teniente primero" y "teniente segundo" es, específicamente lo que lanzó esta línea de investigación.  Me doy cuenta de que ésto es un artículo de una escuela naval en Perú y no de la armada de Perú, pero muy a menudo el sistema de rangos es similar como está preparando a los estudiantes para el ejército real, la armada, la fuerza aérea, etc.  Independientemente de las similitudes o falta de ellas entre una escuela militar y la fuerza armada, me hizo pensar en las diferencias entre las fuerzas armadas latinoamericanas, donde existen, y por cuánto de un país a otro.

Mi solución a ésto fue visitar una tabla de rangos de OTAN para ver los grados listados para los rangos militares de España y al hacerlo, por lo menos tendría un mejor conocimiento de cómo se corresponden los niveles, pero ésto solamente funcionará cuando pueda encontrar información correspondiente para una fuerza armada latinoamericana.  Como un ejemplo, he incluido un imagen de rangos peruanos abajo:

*[Veáse imagen de arriba.]*

Aunque la tabla de OTAN fue fácil de encontrar y leer, todavía me pregunto cómo los rangos militares de cada una fuerza armada latinoamericana en el otro lado del charco corresponden con los de España.

Si esta pregunta es demasiado difícil de responder, no tengo problema en hacer la investigación yo mismo, pero, ¿alguno de ustedes sería tan amable de sugerir algún recursos útil para este tema?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: I assume the grades correspond to how much scrambled egg there is on each epaulette. Or did you mean something different?

Comment: You have a funny way of describing things.  I suppose you could visually examine the epaulettes and compare them to other epaulettes, but knowing how much uniforms can differ between one English speaking country's military and the next, even within the same branch of service (e.g., U.S. Marines vs. British Marines), I'd prefer to have something just a wee bit more official than my discerning eye.

Comment: You do not specify what sort of document you are working with but if it is a technical one I would leave the ranks untranslated so at least they are unambiguous. We have in the past in English used _generalisimo_ for Franco and _comandante Marcos_ without anyone getting too upset. For a novel it is a bit more complicated.

Comment: In Spain, the king is the "commander in chief" (comandante en jefe). The next ranks are: capitan general, general, coronel, teniente coronel, comandante, capitán, teniente, alférez, sub alferez, subteniente, brigada, sargento primero, sargento, cabo primero, cabo, soldado

Comment: It's rather dubious to expect equivalent ranking structures across political boundaries.  The best way to compare ranks between structures is to consider who is unambiguously at the top and count how many direct superior officers are there between a given person and the top guy... The total number of levels may not be the same from country to country, but the distance from the top gives you somewhat of an idea of how to compare ranks across countries.

Comment: For Colombia, you can find the names and NATO equivalences of military degrees here:
**Army:**
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Escalaf%C3%B3n_militar_de_Colombia_(Ej%C3%A9rcito)
**Other branches:**
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Escalaf%C3%B3n_militar_de_Colombia

Also, you can follow similar pages for other countries here:
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categor%C3%ADa:Escalaf%C3%B3n_militar_por_pa%C3%ADs

Comment: @Paul  I like your logic.  That kind of approach could apply to many different situations when working with unknown factors.  Thank you for suggesting it.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón  Gracias para los enlaces (y también por su respuesta).  Inmediatamente después de ver su respuesta, me preguntaba donde tal información podría encontrarse y noté los enlaces nos diste arriba.  ¿Sabe de algo similar para México, Cuba, Nicaragua, Venezuela, y Perú?  Algo similar a las páginas de Wikipedia que existe para Colombia y Argentina sería útil (y, aún mejor, un gráfico que contiene todos ellos).

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón Agradezco cualquier otra información usted o alguien más puede tener en este tema.  Mientras tanto, voy a escribir al portal de Wikipedia para Latinoamérica para ver si algo como esto podría ser en las obras.  De nuevo, gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common ranges in Spanish and their usual translation in English are:

**Army:**

> **soldado** *Private*
>
> **cabo** *Corporal*
>
> **sargento** *Sargent*
>
> **teniente** *Lieutenant*
>
> **capitán** *Captain*
>
> **mayor** *Major*
>
> **coronel** *Colonel*
>
> **general** *General*

Some changes can occur, in Spain an army Major is called *«comandante»*.

A greater change is found in subdivisions. A Second Lieutenant is called *«subteniente»* in Colombia and *«alférez»* in Spain.

Bellow *Colonel* is Lieutenant Colonel, which I find as *«teniente coronel»* both in Spain and Colombia.

For generals, I find:

OF-6 *Brigadier:* *«brigadier general»* in Colombia, *«general de brigada»* in Spain.

OF-7 *Major General:* *«mayor general»* in Colombia, *«general de división»* in Spain.

OF-8 *Lieutenant General:* *«teniente general»* for both Spain and Colombia.

Subdivisions for non-officials are higher. For example in Colombia, OR-1 (Private) is divided between *«soldado regular»*, *«soldado profesional»*, and *«dragoneante»* while in Spain it is only *«soldado»*; while OR-2 (Private) is *«cabo tercero»* in Colombia, and *soldado de primera* in Spain.

**Navy:**

In navy differences are way larger. Using NATO equivalencies I will list Spain, Colombia, and US names.

> OR-1 - **Marinero** ; **Marinero tercero** ; *Seaman Recruit*
>
> OR-2 - **Marinero de primera** ; **Marinero segundo** ; *Seaman Aprentice*
>
> OR-3 - **Cabo** ; **Marinero primero** ; *Seaman*
>
> OR-4 - **Cabo primero** ; **Suboficial tercero** ; *Petty Officer Third Class*
>
> OR-5 - **Cabo mayor** ; **Suboficial segundo** ; *Petty Officer Second Class*
>
> OR-6 - **Sargento** ; **Suboficial primero** ; *Petty Officer First Class*
>
> OR-7 - **Sargento primero** ; **Suboficial jefe** ; *Chief Petty Officer*
>
> OR-8 - **Brigada** ; **Suboficial jefe técnico** ; *Senior Chief Petty Officer*
>
> OR-9 (1) - **Subteniente** ; **Suboficial jefe técnico de comando** ; *Master Chief Petty Officer, Command Master Chief Petty Officer*
>
> OR-9 (2) - **Suboficial mayor** ; **Suboficial jefe técnico de comando conjunto** ; *Fleet/Force Master Chief Petty Officer*
>
> OF(D) - **Guardiamarina** ; N/A ; *Midshipman*
>
> OF-1 (1) - **Alférez de fragata** ; **Teniente de corbeta** ; *Ensign*
>
> OF-1 (2) - **Alférez de navío** ; **Teniente de fragata** ; *Lieutenant (junior grade)*
>
> OF-2 - **Teniente de navío** ; **Teniente de navío** ; *Lieutenant*
>
> OF-3 - **Capitán de corbeta** ; **Capitán de corbeta** ; *Lieutenant Commander*
>
> OF-4 - **Capitán de fragata** ; **Capitán de fragata** ; *Commander*
>
> OF-5 - **Capitán de navío** ; **Capitán de navío** ; *Captain*
>
> OF-6 - **Contra almirante** ; **Contralmirante** ; *Rear Admiral (lower half)*
>
> OF-7 - **Vice almirante** ; **Vicealmirante** ; *Rear Admiral*
>
> OF-8 - **Almirante** ; **Almirante de escuadra** ; *Vice Admiral*
>
> OF-9 - **Almirante general** ; **Almirante** ; *Admiral*
>
> OF-10 - **Capitán general** ; N/A ; *Fleet Admiral*

Comment: ¡Guau!  Estaba pensando a pensar que tendría que responder a mi pregunta mí mismo.  ¡Qué una respuesta exhaustiva!  Bien hecho.  Esta respuesta es definitivamente merecedora de la verde marca de verificación.  Gracias por su tiempo y esfuerzos.